# Send extra data in jquery-inputToken

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send some extra data on server to search using jquery-inputToken

```
<input type="text" id="dsp_filter" name="dsp_ids" />
<input type="text" id="user_filter" name="user_ids" />
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="makeSearch();">Filter Search</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dsp_filter").tokenInput(BASE+"/report-by/filter/dsp", {
            theme: "facebook",
            preventDuplicates: true
        });
        $("#user_filter").tokenInput(BASE+"/report-by/filter/user?dsp_ids="+$('#dsp_filter').val(), {
            theme: "facebook",
            preventDuplicates: true
        });
        $('#toggleElement').on('click', function() {
            $('#filterElements').toggle();
        });
    })
    function makeSearch() {
        console.log('dsp '+$('#dsp_filter').val() + ' user '+$('#user_filter').val() )
    }
</script>
```

In the above code when I click on "Filter Search" I can see the ids, but when I send data from filter user. The data does not get submitted. Can someone tell me how can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$("#user_filter").tokenInput()` is initialised in document ready. So when the document is loaded the value may be empty. However your `makesearch()` is triggered by button that's why it might work.

So move the `$("#user_filter").tokenInput()` to some user event. Or make sure you have values while loading the document.

Comment: I understand the issue, but is there any other way I can do it?? As the dsp_filter could be empty and also I can pre-populate the value.

Comment: Well, move the url generation to a variable. If the value is of the div is null then prepopulate and use the variable inside tokenInput().

Comment: var ids = $('#dsp_filter').val() || "prepoulated_values"; Use this var ids in the tokenInput for URL generation